# meteor dictionary on server with client (session) ids as key

Tags: javascript, meteor

When a client logs in, i want to store inside a dictionary the ids of the clients / sessions as keys inside a dictionary mapped to some data (In case there is no need for a dictionary and meteor has a way to map a single variable with client specific data it would be even better).

I am not familiar with developing Meteor packages and Javascript at all, so my question is: Where do i put this dictionary so i can access it from everywhere on the server and where can i get the clients ids?

Wished behaviour:
1. Client logs in -> Server registers new client id
2. Client calls function on server
3. Inside the function the server gets the right data according to the clients id for further processing

Inside a package (https://github.com/steffow/meteor-accounts-saml) i set up a global variable but when i tried to access it from javascript, inside the imports/api directory, the global variable was undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Presences package to store information about each logged in user, https://github.com/dburles/meteor-presence. It automatically creates unique ids for these.

These database records are available both in the client and server. You can either fork and extend this package to store more information, or create another database table to store your information.